# Why is the image used for a UINavigationBar customization 44 pixels for Retina display and not 88?

Tags: ios

I'm customizing my navigation bar using:

```
   UIImage *anImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"theImage"] 
        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:anImage 
        forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

(In Xcode the image is called "theImage@2x.png") I'm using a tile which 88 pixels high for a retina display. However its coming out twice as tall as I want it. So I looked at this  http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5 and they are using an image 44 high, which has confused me. I was expecting an image 44 should be used for not retina but 88 for retina, but apparently not? WHy so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the standard resolution version, UIKit will automatically load the 2x version(if available) on devices with a retina display.